# How can I pass an Angular2 method in my component as the callback method of a third party library?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got an Angular2 application that references a third party library.  I reference that library in one of my components via:

```
    declare var thirdPartyLib: any;
```

Next I bind a button's click to the method below.

```
    buttonClick() {
        thirdPartyLib.open({
            url: '{url goes here}',
            messageListener: function(eventData) {
                this.processResponse(eventData);
            }
        });
    }

    processResponse(eventData: any) {...}
```

The problem is that when it fires the messageListener function I get an error that it "can't read property processResponse of undefined."  I understand that there is an issue of scoping to 'this', but how do I call that method on my component from within that function?  Or is there another way completely to do something like this?

Just for completeness, I've also attempted the following:

```
    buttonClick() {
        var myMethod = this.processResponse;
        thirdPartyLib.open({
            url: '{url goes here}',
            messageListener: myMethod
        });
    }

    processResponse(eventData: any) {...}
```

The problem with this method is that `processResponse` calls a service as `this.someService.whatever(eventData.something);`.  Using this approach throws the same error but now for `this.someService`.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have two options.

**1. [Arrow functions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html)**

They will preserve the reference to current object in `this`.

```
buttonClick() {
    thirdPartyLib.open({
        url: '{url goes here}',
        messageListener: (eventData) => {
            this.processResponse(eventData);
        }
    });
}

processResponse(eventData: any) {...}
```

Or even shorter form: `messageListener: eventData => this.processResponse(eventData)`

**2. "that" pattern**

`that` (or differently named) variable may hold reference to current object.

```
buttonClick() {
    const that = this;
    thirdPartyLib.open({
        url: '{url goes here}',
        messageListener: function(eventData) {
            that.processResponse(eventData);
        }
    });
}

processResponse(eventData: any) {...}
```